# Embedding YouTube video changes font look on elements outside the iframe

Tags: css, fonts, webkit, youtube, embed

I'm adding a YouTube video to a web page, and it's oddly affecting the existing text on my page. I've narrowed it down to a small example which shows up the problem quite well, at least in Chrome and Safari on Mac:

http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/wjNzf/5/

This is basically a paragraph of text with a video embedded using the current, standard YouTube iframe-based embed below it.

Watch carefully as that page loads, and you'll see the apparent weight of the paragraph of text above the embedded video get lighter when the YouTube embed has finished loading.

The white-on-black look I've chosen shows up the problem quite distinctly, but the "jump to a lighter font" is also there, more subtly, with normal colours.

I can't see any CSS properties changing, and I can't figure out how to override/prevent this change. As far as I can see using webkit's inspection tools, the font style remains the same.

Any ideas how I can fix this? And can other people see it? Starting to think it's something peculiar to my setup...

Here's before and after shots. I grabbed these within a second of each other, one before the video loaded into the page, one after:

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Weird, not seeing it on chrome/linux. Maybe including the video causes it to switch from a software renderer to a hardware renderer or something?

Comment: @GGG Thanks for checking! It certainly *feels* like the renderer is changing, but the styles aren't. Like maybe it's changing the sub-pixel rendering, rather than the actual font weight. It's weird. I'm going to embed a couple of images that show the "before" and "after", which might help people understand what I'm seeing.

Comment: Just to add that I am not seeing a difference in chrome/IE/FF on windows

Comment: @TheWaxMann Thanks for checking. It's definitely not specific to a *computer*, because it's also happening on another Mac I've got. Though it doesn't happen in Firefox for me. Maybe's it's specific to OSX and Webkit. I'll do a bit more testing on other platforms when I can get to them...

Comment: I have this problem too!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474381/webkit-font-rendering-when-flash-content-is-embedded. Still no solution in sight?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing : antialiased;
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found your post on this bizarre issue. It's affecting both the sites I manage, but only in webkit browsers on Mac, AFAIK. Mac Firefox renders the text fine, even in the presence of the embedded video.

These pages have video embeds and show the problem clearly. You can probably watch the text switch from robust (normal) rendering to "dim" - no subpixel font smoothing.

> http://makanipower.com/why-airborne-wind/
>
> http://andrewnimmo.com/mistersaturdaynight/

For comparison check out these pages without videos:

> http://makanipower.com/faq/
>
> http://andrewnimmo.com/mistersaturdaynight/2009/09/justin-carter-2/

Just contributing to the problem exhibit, since I have no clue why it's happening. I've seen people proposing jquery conflicts but on andrewnimmo.com i've killed ALL javascript in the head, disabling my js menus for example.

These are both Wordpress installs fwiw.

Curiously the problem is not replicated on the live version of the second site,

> http://mistersaturdaynight.com/

which uses a different wp theme (coraline). And also, has some javascript. Fonts are smoothed perfectly.

The two sites with problems are running on very similar WP theme code, but I can't find anything suspicious, outside the js that I've eliminated on one of them without solving the problem.

Comment: It looks to me like the difference between -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; and -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; ...i'm using this as an example: http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing

Comment: Thanks Gaurav - i was an absolute newbie at the time of the post and was not allowed to post multiple links!!

Comment: Man, I just disabled ALL the javascript on the andrewnimmo.com site, thinking it might be interfering, and I'm still getting the jagged text. And I'm still NOT getting the jagged text on mistersaturdaynight.com, although it has both iframes and js.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can narrow down the problem at my end given your helpful info.

Comment: Interesting. I think you're right about the font smoothing -- in my jsFiddle example, if I specifically set `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` on the body, the look of the text remains the same before and after the video loads. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/wjNzf/10/).

Comment: yes that's it - and I can't find anything in my other pages explicitly overriding the -webkit-font-smoothing setting , either!

Comment: This might even be some odd webkit bug. Will have to play more when I get the time, but that probably won't be until next week :(

Comment: I'm having this issue too :( The suggested work-around of putting -webkit-font-smoothing on the body is not working for me though. I'm also seeing the bug in the jsfiddle that was posted and claimed to be working.